# How to operate matrices within nested lists?

Tags: r, list, matrix, nested

I am newbie using nested lists. So, let´s suppose that my data has the following `dput`:

```
mat_lag <- list(structure(list(V1 = 3:7, V2 = 11:15, V3 = 19:23), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(V1 = 2:6, V2 = 10:14, 
V3 = 18:22), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), 
structure(list(V1 = 1:5, V2 = 9:13, V3 = 17:21), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame"))
```

and

```
PHI <- list(list(structure(1:9, .Dim = c(3L, 3L)), structure(1:9, .Dim = c(3L, 
3L)), structure(1:9, .Dim = c(3L, 3L))), list(structure(1:9, .Dim = c(3L, 
3L)), structure(1:9, .Dim = c(3L, 3L)), structure(1:9, .Dim = c(3L, 
3L))))
```

My idea is multiple the 3 matrices in `mat_lag` with the 3 matrices inside the nested lists in `PHI`. My problem is that I am not sure how to manipulate nested listed, and I could program the code for only one nested list.

Let me explain better. I am looking for an entry-by-entry multiplication

If I am using `PHI[[1]]` the code will be the following:

```
Product <- lapply(1:length(mat_lag), function(index)
  mapply(function(x, y) x*y, t(PHI[[1]][[index]]), mat_lag[[index]]))
```

and the result will be the following:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    3   44  133    6   55  152    9   66  171
[2,]    4   48  140    8   60  160   12   72  180
[3,]    5   52  147   10   65  168   15   78  189
[4,]    6   56  154   12   70  176   18   84  198
[5,]    7   60  161   14   75  184   21   90  207

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    2   40  126    4   50  144    6   60  162
[2,]    3   44  133    6   55  152    9   66  171
[3,]    4   48  140    8   60  160   12   72  180
[4,]    5   52  147   10   65  168   15   78  189
[5,]    6   56  154   12   70  176   18   84  198

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1   36  119    2   45  136    3   54  153
[2,]    2   40  126    4   50  144    6   60  162
[3,]    3   44  133    6   55  152    9   66  171
[4,]    4   48  140    8   60  160   12   72  180
[5,]    5   52  147   10   65  168   15   78  189
```

I want to repeat this operation when `PHI`changes, it means I want to use `PHI[[1]]` and `PHI[[2]]`.

I thought that I could use a `for` loop or maybe `function` but I am using `function` for defining the index in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product <- lapply(1:length(PHI), function(index)
  lapply(1:length(mat_lag), function(z)
    mapply(function(x, y) x*y, t(PHI[[index]][[z]]), mat_lag[[index]])
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a multitude of ways to achieve what you're seeking. (I assume you want matrix multiplication `%*%` and not entry-by-entry multiplication `*`. Here I'll use tcrossprod)
Here's 2 options

## Multiple for loops

```
result1 <- vector('list', 3)
for(i in 1:3){
  result1[[i]] <- vector('list', 3)
  for(j in 1:2){
    result1[[i]][[j]] <- tcrossprod(PHI[[j]][[i]], mat_lag[[i]])
  }
}
```

## Nested lapply functions (loop hiding)

```
result2 <- lapply(1:3, function(x)lapply(1:2, function(z){
  tcrossprod(PHI[[z]][[x]], mat_lag[[x]])
}))
```

Both use indices to iterate over the lists.
We can almost replicate this using `mapply`

```
result3 <- lapply(1:2, function(x)mapply(function(x, y) tcrossprod(x, y), x = PHI[[x]], y = mat_lag))
```

But this returns the result as one large matrix output (and transposes the result), so some further formatting would've to be done.

Comment: I am trying to do an entry-by-entry multiplication, although it sounds a little crazy. I edit my post in order to explain better my question